# Ref in mongoose model not giving output

Tags: node.js, mongoose, backend, mern

I am using mongoose for defining schema. I have two schemas user and Userdetail. i want data from user in userdetail

I have below schema but i am not getting the output. i think the code is correct but not getting why there is no output...instead i am getting empty array.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const UserDetailSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    Phone : {
        type : Number
    },
    FirstName : {
        type : String
    },
    LastName : {
        type : String
    },
    productimage : {
        data : Buffer,
        contentType : String
    },
    IsDeleted:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
    },
    UserID : {
        type : String,
    },
    data : [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "user"
    }],
},
{timestamps: true})

const UserDetail = new mongoose.model("userdetail",UserDetailSchema);

module.exports = UserDetail;
```

my user schema is,

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      IsDeleted:{
        type:Boolean
      },
    },
    {timestamps: true});

    module.exports = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

query is,

```
<pre>

router.get("/UserDetail",async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        const UsersData= await UserDetail.find();
        res.json(UsersData)
    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).json({ message: e.message })
    }
})

</pre>
```

Even though i am using only find, i must get the data with only id right?

Output is -

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

```
 router.patch("/UserDetail/:id",Auth,upload.single("productimage"),async(req,res)=>{

    try{


        const id = req.params.id;

        const updatedData = req.body;

        updatedData.productimage = {data: fs.readFileSync('upload/' + req.file.filename),
        contentType: 'image/png'};
        const options = { new: true };


        const result = await UserDetail.findOneAndUpdate(
            id, updatedData, options
        )

        res.send(result)
    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).json({ message: e.message })
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you share the query which you are writing ?

Comment: Sure Khalid...I have updated the que..

Comment: Post you data stored in the db. Are there any ids in the array stored in the db?

Comment: Hi Marc, there is no array in db, this square bracket is there because i gave it in the model (please refer data values i have put in array in userdetail schema)....If i dont  give square bracket, it shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need a little change in userID in schema of userDetail.Please make it to `UserID:{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId},` as it will help you in future during aggregation and you can also remove data from your userDetail model as it will not store any data until you save it.And lastly try to run this aggregation query.

```
 const UsersData= await UserDetails.aggregate([
    {$lookup:
     {
     from: "users",
     localField: "userID",
     foreignField: "_id",
     as: "data" 
     }
    }])
```

In this way your respective details of users will be displayed in array of data.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in your model and then populate the data.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const UserDetailSchema = mongoose.Schema({
Phone : {
    type : Number
},
FirstName : {
    type : String
},
LastName : {
    type : String
},
productimage : {
    data : Buffer,
    contentType : String
},
IsDeleted:{
    type:Boolean,
    default:false
},
UserID : {
    type : String,
},
data : {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user"
},
},
{timestamps: true})
}
```

populate query

```
let Model=//import your model here
let userdata=await Model.find().populate("data")
console.log(userdata)
```